# What does this "python -" do?

Tags: bash

I see this command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py | python -
```

What does this to? What is the "-" called in bash?

Comment: It isn't called anything "in bash".  As far as `bash` is concerned, it is just a parameter passed to the `python` command.  Python interprets as meaning "read the script from standard input".  (Read `man python`)

Comment: Not to be confused with a Unicode hyphen or dash character (see https://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html) ... which will thoroughly confuse `python` ... and you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bash. `-` [has a very specific meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) when passed to the python binary:

> `-`
>
> Read commands from standard input (sys.stdin). [...]

Since, in your example,

- `curl` outputs the downloaded file to stdout and
- the shell pipe `|` passes curl's output to python's stdin,

python will execute the commands contained in the file downloaded by curl.

---

Note that this is a convention commonly found in various command-line utilities: Providing a single hyphen in place of a file name causes the command to read input from stdin instead of a file.

Comment: And not just `python`: use of `-` to represent standard input and standard output is a common convention, notably used by many utilities described in the POSIX standard.

Comment: Common ... but not universal.

Comment: @chepner: Indeed, thanks for mentioning that. I have added a note to my answer.